# How to access to object property?

Tags: laravel, object, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

```
MyObject {#300 ▼
  +dataType: DataType {#323 ▶}
  +data: Course {#328 ▼
    #connection: "mysql"
    #table: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: array:32 [▶]
    #original: array:32 [▶]
    #changes: array:2 [▼
      "prop" => 1
      "updated_at" => "2018-08-08 11:50:39"
    ]
    #casts: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #dispatchesEvents: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #fillable: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  }
}
```

I print on screen this object using

```
dd($args->data);
```

now I need to check if there are something inside changes
then I try to access to the property with:

```
dd($args->data->changes);
```

or

```
dd($args->data['changes']);
```

but instead of the array, that you can see above, I got always a NULL.
How can I access to "changes"?

Comment: what about`dd($args['data']['changes])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data seems to be an Eloquent model. The `changes` property is a **protected** member of the model class. Therefore, you cannot access it from outside.

In the output of `dd` functions, public members are prefixed with the `+` character, protected members are prefixed with the `#` character. You can see those prefixes to know the visibility of the property that you want to access.

To get the changes of an Eloquent model, use the `getChanges()` method. In your case, you should write code like this:

```
dd($args->data->getChanges());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$args->data->getChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, check whether the object is present or not.If the object is present then try to access its `key`.So, here is the code:

```
$changes = $args->data ? $args->data->changes : [];
if(count($changes)>0){
 // iterate through the `$changes` to make changes 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with foreach loop

```
foreach($args as $arguslist){
$mainarray = $argulist->changes;
$arrayattr = $argulist->changes->prop;
}
```